# Can't create new user in Google Cloud mysql instance

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

Can't create new user for MySQL instance with root account.

```
mysql> create user 'user'@'%' identified by '#########';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'user'@'%'
mysql> select user();
+--------------------+
| user()             |
+--------------------+
| root@x.x.x.x       |
+--------------------+
```

Also can't create it via the Google Console. There is no "Create user account" button as [described in docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/create-manage-user-mysql?hl=en_US&_ga=1.112771716.1023944920.1465912854#creating).

How to create a new one?

Comment: Can you run "SHOW GRANTS" as well? The root user is root@'%', instead of root@x.x.x.x

Comment: @Tianzhou show grants:
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: Try this? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34940/adding-a-user-to-mysql-with-name-fails-with-error-1396

Comment: @Tianzhou it is ok but not for Google Cloud SQL